# Kubernetes not loading mongo deployment. "Invalid value ... field is immutable"

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I'm getting the following error when running `skaffold dev` on my microservices project.  I literally taken the code straight out of a tutorial on microservices, but am still getting the error:

```
The Deployment "orders-mongo-depl" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"orders-mongo"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
kubectl apply: exit status 1
```

Here is my "orders-mongo-depl.yaml" file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orders-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orders-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orders-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: orders-mongo
          image: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orders-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: orders-mongo
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Here is my skaffold.yaml file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: stephengrider/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: stephengrider/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '**/*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: stephengrider/tickets
      context: tickets
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: stephengrider/orders
      context: orders
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

I have tried restarting skaffold, deleting and restarting Minikube, changing the minikube driver between virtualbox and docker, and restarting my computer.  I am on the latest version of ubuntu and have up to date minikube, kubernetes and docker.

Comment: Compare your labels in the Deployment with the Deployment in the cluster, they must have the same labels and selector.

Comment: It looks like there were changes in `selector`, same error happens if `selector` is changed and manifest is applied again. You can try to clean skaffold objects by issuing `skaffold delete` command. It's described [here](https://skaffold.dev/docs/tutorials/artifact-dependencies/#cleanup). If it doesn't help, please share tutorial you're following

Comment: I was able to issue ```skaffold delete``` a few days ago and it worked as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer out of comments since it resolved the issue.

**Short answer**

To cleanup all deployments and objects, following command should be issued:

`skaffold delete`

**A bit more details**

During development and testing objects are created. When any changes are done within the config or objects itself, error is fired e.g.

```
The Deployment "orders-mongo-depl" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"orders-mongo"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

Short test in kubernetes showed that changing `selector` in service or development producing exactly the same error which leads to necessity to correct manifest/objects or reset deployments in `skaffold` if not clear where discrepancy comes from.

[Skaffold cleanup reference](https://skaffold.dev/docs/tutorials/artifact-dependencies/#cleanup)